# BigQuery clustering : hit clustering with multiple keys

Tags: google-bigquery

We have a table which is partitioned on time (512Mbyte / partition) and it has also a cluster key on customer_id and time.

Up to now we had these queries, which are working well:

```sql
SELECT column FROM TABLE WHERE customer_id = 'key' and time > '2021-11-10'

SELECT column FROM TABLE WHERE customer_id IN ('key1', 'key2') and time > '2021-11-10'
```

Today we are trying these queries:

```sql
SELECT column FROM TABLE WHERE customer_id IN (SELECT customer_id FROM customers) AND time > '2021-11-10'
```

We see that this query not uses the clustering, resulting in getting a lot more data out of BigQuery. Then i found this article, explaining that complex filtering does not work with clustering https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-clustered-tables#do_not_use_clustered_columns_in_complex_filter_expressions

Is there a solution to define a list of id's outside the query and inject it into the query? (because now we need to generate the list of id into code).

Thx in Advance,
Regards

Comment: The thing is that the condition should be constant. In your case its dynamic.

Comment: Thx Mr.Batra, that makes sense. So the next question is can i embed a list of ids into 'something' outside my query, and then inject it into my query, because if something is defined outside my query is it then not seen by the query optimizer as something which is not dynamically or is it just a best practise to always hit the cluster with on id, in my case customer_id? Thx

Comment: Additionally, i made a mistake in my question above. This query works: WHERE customer_id IN ('key1', 'key2'), a subquery does not work probably as you said this it dynamic behaviour. So my new question would be, is it possible to generate a list of keys outside the query and inject it into the query?

Comment: Until the list is static/constant/hard-coded its fine.

Comment: Hello Mr.Batra, i have now created this below query into the bigquery GUI and this works until i exceed the limit of the ARRAY (1Mbyte), which in my specific case was about 16000 items. Probably in coding this would not happen because it is hardcoded, however i cannot ask from devs that they add 16000 items into a query. Would this be the moment to conclude that a cluster on device id (my above example showed customer but actually we use device id as cluster) is not correct and we would better choose customer for example, then we will never hit the cluster on that many items.

Comment: although we sometimes only need some device id's, may be we should add device id to the cluster as well? Anyway many thx for the guidance.                                    
                                                                                                                           
The query: DECLARE X array<string>;
SET X = (ARRAY
        (SELECT device_id FROM `table` WHERE customer_id = 'key') 
        ));

SELECT mydata FROM `table` WHERE device_id IN UNNEST(X) and day > "2021-09-10";

Comment: What would be your idea about partitioning on 512Mbye on time + a cluster with 'customerId,device_id,time? On customer can have about 10000 devices. We always have one or more customers in the query, we want to retrieve data between one and all the devices per customer, and have hour, day, month selection in time for each device.  Thx

Comment: Clustering is a performance thing and Performance always comes with a trade off. You need to see how many queries that you fire have which column the most and certain other aspects. It depends upon the queries you fire on this table not table structure.

Comment: According to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/clustered-tables), if the table or partition is under 1GB there won’t be any significant difference in query performance between a clustered and unclustered table.  Also, clustering is preferred over partitioning if partitioning results in a small amount of data per partition(approximately less than 1GB). Is there any specific reason you are using partitioning?

Comment: Hello Mr.Batra. Our customers own devices. Our querries have mostly only one customer_id and always a time period (day, week, moth, or year). The customer owns devices and the querries contain one to many device_id's per customer. I understand now that it is indeed a balance to make most of the querries happy, but doing that for all is kind of impossible, unless you duplicate data in different tables for example.

Comment: Hello Sakshi Gatyan, the table that i talk about does not contain a lot of data indeed (only 20GByte), but we do a lot of queries on it (which mostly are cached by BigQuery, such a beautiful feature). We partitioned it to scan less data. However with your feedback i could conclude that we do not need partitioning at all at the moment. With both your feedback i would say i am going to load test clustering with 'customer_id-time' and then 'time-customer_id'. 'time-customer_id' would be more granular right? Thx

Comment: Is it possible that for really small tables (100Mbyte) bigquery doesn't care about the cluster and just skips it as the overhead may be bigger then the profit? That said, our next project will be volumes of TB, this will change stuff i guess although it seems also little for such a power full solution as bigquery :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concluding the discussion from the comments:

Partitioning and Clustering are used to improve query performance and control costs of querying heavy data.
Partition helps segment the data into partitions and clustering organises the data based on specified columns ie. clustered columns.

As mentioned in [this](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/clustered-tables) documentation, in order for clustering to work efficiently, your table/partition should be greater than or approximately 1GB.
In your case if you're trying clustering on 512MB of data, there won't be any significant difference in query performance. You should prefer clustering over partitioning if partitioning results in a small amount of data per partition(approximately less than 1GB).

Refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/clustered-tables#when_to_use_clustering) for more information.